# What is Snow's granddaughter's name in "The Hunger Games"?

Tags: names, the-hunger-games

Does anybody know what President Snow's granddaughter's name is?

Comment: It's hard to tell as the Inuits have sixty different names for her.

Comment: I expect that President Snow knows her name.

Comment: This is great! I was also wondering what her name was! Even though I highly doubted that President Snow would ever have kids, given how he is . . .

Answer (score 13):

#### President Snow’s granddaughter is not named.

Snow’s granddaughter is never given a name. She is only ever mentioned once in the books, at the end of Mockingjay when Coin holds the vote for whether there should be one last Hunger Games using Capitol children.

> "It was mine," says Coin. "It seemed to balance the need for vengeance with the least loss of life. You may cast your votes."
>
> "No!" bursts out Peeta. "I vote no, of course! We can't have another Hunger Games!"
>
> "Why not?" Johanna retorts. "It seems very fair to me. Snow even has a granddaughter. I vote yes." 
> <sub><sup>*- Mockingjay (Chapter 26)*</sup></sub>

She is seen more in the movies, as a presence beside her grandfather, but she is not given a name in them, either. The [IMDB page](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm4794787/) for the actress lists her part only as “Snow’s Granddaughter”.

#### Note: the name supplied by Google is not canon - it is from a fanfiction.

While a Google search for “president snow granddaughter” returns the first result as Celestia Snow, that is not actually based on any official information on the series.

[image: Google Search result onebox, showing the result "Celestia Snow" from The 66th Hunger Games Wiki on Fandom]

Following the link to the page displayed leads to a page of a wiki whose subject is a Hunger Games fanfiction, not the actual books or movies.

> The 66th Hunger Games is a book series written online on the site Wattpad by Michiel B.L. Korte. It is a fanfiction of the original Hunger Games (as you might have guessed) and has two sequels on the writing website "Wattpad": "The 66th Victory Tour" and "The 66th Mentoring". It's about 15 year old Maika Sheert who is reaped into the Hunger Games. These books also describe pasts of Victors from Catching Fire and you'll get to know how Tigris lost her job, how Cashmere became a prostitute and why Snow's granddaughter joined the rebels. 
> <sub><sup>*[- The 66th Hunger Games Wiki (Homepage)](https://the-66th-hunger-games.fandom.com/wiki/The_66th_Hunger_Games_Wiki)*</sup></sub>

The information on this wiki therefore cannot be considered accurate. This name also appears as the name of President Snow’s granddaughter played by Erika Bierman in the movies on the 34th Hunger Games Wiki, which is a different wiki whose subject is also a Hunger Games fanfiction.

> The 34th Hunger Games Wiki is a collaborative encyclopedia about a fan-made story set in the world of "The Hunger Games" franchise. 
> <sub><sup>*[- The 34th Hunger Games Wiki (Homepage)](https://34th-hunger-games-fanon.fandom.com/wiki/34th_Hunger_Games_Wiki)*</sup></sub>

Therefore, while the name does show up on some websites, it is not official in origin and should not be taken as canon.

Comment: I've seen it mentioned as 'Celestia'...

Comment: @Valorum [That's](https://the-66th-hunger-games.fandom.com/wiki/Celestia_Snow) fan-fiction. (Note that the link isn't even to the Hunger Games wikia, which itself is often full of nonsense, but to a wikia for "the 66th Hunger Games" which is a piece of fanfic written by someone else.)

Comment: Celestia's name is an interesting choice. Compared to Snow's evil, she really is a "celestial"